# How to create a detailed report in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, reportviewer

I want to create a report with very detailed data in ASP.NET. This report should be exportable to PDF and Excel. Can you tell me tips on how to do this kind of report?

I'm having a problem linking up my datasets in ReportViewer.

You will find below a screenshot of what I want :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using iTextSharp download:

```
        using iTextSharp.text;
        using iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser;
        using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=this.pdf");
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
        HtmlForm frm = new HtmlForm();
        GridView1.AllowPaging = false;
        GridView1.Parent.Controls.Add(frm);
        frm.Controls.Add(GridView1);
        frm.RenderControl(hw);
        StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());
        Document PDFdoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10.0F, 10.0F, 10.0F, 0.0F);
        iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker htmlparser =   new iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker(PDFdoc);
        PdfWriter.GetInstance(PDFdoc, Response.OutputStream);
        PDFdoc.Open();
        htmlparser.Parse(sr);
        PDFdoc.Close();
        Response.Write(PDFdoc);
        Response.End();
```

To Excel:

```
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", "YourExcelFile.xls"));
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
        System.IO.StringWriter sw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
        System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter hw = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(sw);
        GridView1.AllowPaging = false;
        GridView1.RenderControl(hw);
        Response.Write(sw.ToString());
        Response.End();
```

Comment: No.. I want to create a report first in ASP.Net